# twisted twitter streaming api bad request error

Tags: python, twitter, twisted

I am using python twisted to get streaming data from twitter streaming api.There are two steps in short. 1) get access_token 2) use access_token to make request for the data.
step 1 work completely fine but at step 2 i am gettin gthis error of `bad request` `status 400`. why is so? I think its because twitter uses `HTTP1.1` and twisted is using `HTTP1.0` by deafult. then how to upgrade connections to `HTTP1.1`

**EDIT:** Here is my error message

```
HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request
content-length: 0
date: Sun, 12 Mar 2017 14:57:13 GMT
server: tsa
x-connection-hash: dca361a2b4214ad66203e9912b05cf7f

[Failure instance: Traceback (failure with no frames): <class 'twisted.internet.error.ConnectionDone'>: Connection was closed cleanly.
```

.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import oauth2 as oauth
import urlparse
import time
import webbrowser
from twisted.internet import reactor, protocol, ssl
from twisted.web import http


CONSUMER_KEY = 'xxxx'
CONSUMER_SECRET = 'xxxx'
CONSUMER = oauth.Consumer(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)

ACCESS_TOKEN_FILE = 'OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN'

TWITTER_REQUEST_TOKEN_URL = 'https://twitter.com/oauth/request_token'
TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_URL = 'https://twitter.com/oauth/access_token'
TWITTER_AUTHORIZE_URL = 'https://twitter.com/oauth/authorize'
TWITTER_STREAM_API_HOST = 'stream.twitter.com'
TWITTER_STREAM_API_PATH = '/1.1/statuses/sample.json'


class TwitterStreamer(http.HTTPClient):
    def connectionMade(self):
        self.sendCommand('GET', self.factory.url)
        self.sendHeader('Host', self.factory.host)
        self.sendHeader('User-Agent', self.factory.agent)
        self.sendHeader('Authorization', self.factory.oauth_header)
        self.endHeaders()

    def handleStatus(self, version, status, message):
        if status != '200':
            self.factory.tweetError(ValueError("bad status"))

    def lineReceived(self, line):
        self.factory.tweetReceived(line)

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        self.factory.tweetError(reason)


class TwitterStreamerFactory(protocol.ClientFactory):
    protocol = TwitterStreamer

    def __init__(self, oauth_header):
        self.url = TWITTER_STREAM_API_PATH
        self.agent = 'Twisted/TwitterStreamer'
        self.host = TWITTER_STREAM_API_HOST
        self.oauth_header = oauth_header

    def clientConnectionFailed(self, _, reason):
        self.tweetError(reason)

    def tweetReceived(self, tweet):
        print tweet

    def tweetError(self, error):
        print error


def save_access_token(key, secret):
    with open(ACCESS_TOKEN_FILE, 'w') as f:
        f.write("ACCESS_KEY=%s\n" % key)
        f.write("ACCESS_SECRET=%s\n" % secret)


def load_access_token():
    with open(ACCESS_TOKEN_FILE) as f:
        lines = f.readlines()

    str_key = lines[0].strip().split('=')[1]
    str_secret = lines[1].strip().split('=')[1]
    return oauth.Token(key=str_key, secret=str_secret)


def fetch_access_token():
    CONSUMER_KEY = 'xxxxxxxx'
    CONSUMER_SECRET = 'xxxxxxxxx'
    ACCESS_KEY="xxxxxxx"
    ACCESS_SECRET="xxxxxxxxx"
    consumer = oauth.Consumer(key=CONSUMER_KEY, secret=CONSUMER_SECRET)
    access_token = oauth.Token(key=ACCESS_KEY, secret=ACCESS_SECRET)

    return (access_token.key, access_token.secret)


def build_authorization_header(access_token):
    url = "https://%s%s" % (TWITTER_STREAM_API_HOST, TWITTER_STREAM_API_PATH)
    params = {
        'oauth_version': "1.0",
        'oauth_nonce': oauth.generate_nonce(),
        'oauth_timestamp': str(int(time.time())),
        'oauth_token': access_token.key,
        'oauth_consumer_key': CONSUMER.key
    }

    # Sign the request.
    # For some messed up reason, we need to specify is_form_encoded to prevent
    # the oauth2 library from setting oauth_body_hash which Twitter doesn't like.
    req = oauth.Request(method="GET", url=url, parameters=params, is_form_encoded=True)
    req.sign_request(oauth.SignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1(), CONSUMER, access_token)

    # Grab the Authorization header
    header = req.to_header()['Authorization'].encode('utf-8')
    print "Authorization header:"
    print "     header = %s" % header
    return header

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Check if we have saved an access token before.
    try:
        f = open(ACCESS_TOKEN_FILE)
    except IOError:
        # No saved access token. Do the 3-legged OAuth dance and fetch one.
        (access_token_key, access_token_secret) = fetch_access_token()
        # Save the access token for next time.
        save_access_token(access_token_key, access_token_secret)

    # Load access token from disk.
    access_token = load_access_token()

    # Build Authorization header from the access_token.
    auth_header = build_authorization_header(access_token)

    # Twitter stream using the Authorization header.
    twsf = TwitterStreamerFactory(auth_header)
    reactor.connectSSL(TWITTER_STREAM_API_HOST, 443, twsf, ssl.ClientContextFactory())
    reactor.run()
```

UPDATE: Working code:

```
import base64, urllib
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.internet.defer import Deferred
from twisted.protocols import basic
from twisted.python.failure import DefaultException
from twisted.web.client import Agent
from twisted.web.http_headers import Headers
import json
import oauth2 as oauth
import time
from twisted.web import server,resource
from twisted.internet import endpoints
from twisted.web.server import Site
CONSUMER_KEY = 'xxxxxxxxxxxx'
CONSUMER_SECRET = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
TWITTER_STREAM_API_HOST = 'stream.twitter.com'
TWITTER_STREAM_API_PATH = '/1.1/statuses/sample.json'
ACCESS_TOKEN_FILE = 'OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN'

CONSUMER = oauth.Consumer(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)


def callback(result):
    print result
def errback(error):
    print error

class StreamingParser(basic.LineReceiver):
    delimiter = '\r\n'

    def __init__(self, user_callback, user_errback):
        self.user_callback = user_callback
        self.user_errback = user_errback

    def lineReceived(self, line):
        d = Deferred()
        d.addCallback(self.user_callback)
        d.addErrback(self.user_errback)
        line = line.strip()
        print line,'........'
        try:
            d.callback(json.loads(line))
        except ValueError, e:
            if self.user_errback:
                d.errback(e)

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        if self.user_errback:
            d = Deferred()
            d.addErrback(self.user_errback)
            d.errback(DefaultException(reason.getErrorMessage()))

def _get_response(response, callback, errback):
    print 'got response......'
    response.deliverBody(StreamingParser(callback, errback))
    return Deferred()

def _shutdown(reason, errback):
    d = Deferred()
    d.addErrback(errback)
    d.errback(reason)
    if reactor.running:
        reactor.stop()

def save_access_token(key, secret):
    with open(ACCESS_TOKEN_FILE, 'w') as f:
    f.write("ACCESS_KEY=%s\n" % key)
    f.write("ACCESS_SECRET=%s\n" % secret)


def load_access_token():
    with open(ACCESS_TOKEN_FILE) as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

    str_key = lines[0].strip().split('=')[1]
    str_secret = lines[1].strip().split('=')[1]
    return oauth.Token(key=str_key, secret=str_secret)


def fetch_access_token():
    ACCESS_KEY="xxxxx-xxxx"
    ACCESS_SECRET="xxxxxxxxxxxx"
    access_token = oauth.Token(key=ACCESS_KEY, secret=ACCESS_SECRET)
    return (access_token.key, access_token.secret)


def make_header(access_token):
    url = "https://%s%s" % (TWITTER_STREAM_API_HOST, TWITTER_STREAM_API_PATH)
    params = {
     # "Authorization": "Oauth %s" % auth,
     "oauth_version": "1.0",
     "oauth_nonce": oauth.generate_nonce(),
     "oauth_timestamp": str(int(time.time())),
     "oauth_token": access_token.key,
     "oauth_consumer_key": CONSUMER.key
     }

    req = oauth.Request(method="GET", url=url, parameters=params, is_form_encoded=True)
    req.sign_request(oauth.SignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1(), CONSUMER, access_token)
    header = req.to_header()['Authorization'].encode('utf-8')
    print "Authorization header:"
    print "     header = %s" % header
    return header

def start_streaming():
    print 'streaming started...........'
    try:
        f = open(ACCESS_TOKEN_FILE)
    except IOError:
        access_token_key, access_token_secret = fetch_access_token()
        save_access_token(access_token_key, access_token_secret)

    access_token = load_access_token()
    auth_header = make_header(access_token)
    url = 'https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/sample.json'
    headers = Headers({
        'User-Agent': ['TwistedSTreamReciever'],
        'Authorization': [auth_header]})
    agent = Agent(reactor)
    d = agent.request('GET', url, headers, None)
    d.addCallback(_get_response, callback, errback)
    d.addBoth(_shutdown, errback)
    # reactor.run()

class _Stream(resource.Resource):
    isLeaf = True
    def render_GET(self, request):
        start_streaming()# Streaming started here.......
        time.sleep(8) # wait for 8 seconds...
        ########.........??? stop streaming here??
        return "<html>streaming started...........%s</html>" % (time.ctime(),)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    resource = _Stream()
    factory = Site(resource)
    endpoint = endpoints.TCP4ServerEndpoint(reactor, 8880)
    endpoint.listen(factory)
    reactor.run()
```

Comment: Why are you using `twisted.web.http.HTTPClient`?  Use `Agent` instead.

Comment: @Jean-PaulCalderone thanks for the reply. i will try to make use of Agent

Comment: I got it working with `Agent` . i also defined an http endpoint to start streaming. now just a little hint i need on how to stop the streaming ( maybe stop the Connection strted by `Agent`). i have added my updated code for reference

Comment: for reference about my current doubt please check `_Stream` class in above code

Comment: i tried for a while and got something working . what i did is inside `start_streaming` function ,after calling `agent.request` i set a attribute on `d(returned deffered) `  .    `d._streamName = someName` and added this deferred to  global variable `_dSet` that contains all the deffereds returned by agent class. now i made an endpoint which when called loops tthrough `_dSet` and if name matches i call `d.cancel` is this correct way of doing?

Answer (score 0):

To give up on reading a particular streaming response (which it seems may be necessary - I'm guessing these Twitter streams never end on their own) and close the connection associated with that request/response (because HTTP has no other way to give up on a response), use the body delivery protocol's `transport.loseConnection` method.  So, for example:

```
def _get_response(response, callback, errback):
    print 'got response......'
    proto = StreamingParser(callback, errback)
    save_stream_by_name(stream_name, proto)
    response.deliverBody(proto)
    return Deferred()
```

When you're done with that stream:

```
pop_stream_by_name(stream_name).transport.loseConnection()
```